# Merge upstream branch into fork with rewritten history

Tags: git

Is there any good approach to merge forked repositories with same files/folders structure on the HEAD, but different history? Not fully automated workflow is acceptable, since it won't be done very often - but I hope there is better way than copying all files and checking differences manually.:)

Background is that we had to migrate from 10-years-old TFS repository to Git. There was a requirement to keep whole history, but only for master branch. After migrating from TFS - we cleaned up Git repository a bit, but it's still too big for Git.

We migrated it and this branch is still being used for current production deployments. There are also fixes being done in that production branch - so it cannot be ditched for some time, and these fixes are also important to keep.

In parallel we are working on major refactorings in a separate branch, where a lot of current production codebase is still used, but on the other hand - a lot of historical stuff was removed or moved to different repositories.

What I wanted to do is to make a fork and rewrite history (e.g. using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)), to cleanup all removed projects/objects.

This cleanup part worked well, however we also need possibility to merge changes done on current *production* branch (only one-way - from *production* to *cleaned-up* repo). I tried to do it with adding upstream branch from old repository, but merging upstream repository to repository with rewritten history - makes all cleanup useless. It re-adds all removed objects..

Is there any way to solve it? Maybe such cleanup can be done in some completely different way?
There are a lot of similar questions, but didn't find exactly what I need.:)

Comment: "After migrating from TFS - we cleaned up Git repository a bit, but it's still too big for Git." . . . you know [Microsoft keeps the entirety of all Windows history in a single Git repo](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/90-of-windows-devs-now-using-git-creating-1760-windows-builds-per-day/), right?  Please provide some concrete details, simply characterizing an effort leaves people having to imagine  what's going on, both what you're trying and what's going wrong..

Comment: Yes, I heard and read how Microsoft moved whole Windows codebase to Git, but it was "epic" story and they had many challenges. It wasn't something that they just migrated to Git and then instantly became happy with it. For instance - Microsoft also invented GFVS to make it smoother. ;)
My repository is really miles away from the size of Windows repository,  but I just know and see that there are totally obsolete objects, that are doubles the size of repository. They were added, then removed after some time, but still in history.

Comment: One of real-life case I'm trying optimize is related to continuous integration builds. We have TeamCity server, with many automatically spawned build agents shared by many teams. These agents are often recreated from scratch, so they often need to do clean (not "incremental") checkout. If you have long build chain, with many builds - it has really sensible impact on total build time.
I believe there are other way to improve at least this case. However knowing our Git repository is also not perfect and can be improved - it's the one of the options, so why not to work on it.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update* - After reading comments and reviewing my answer, there are some things that can be clarified, some tweaks that will make it easier to use correctly, and one or two outright errors.  Sorry about that; as docs go the original answer was "rough draft" quality.  I'll address a couple questions first, but I do recommend having a look over the edited answer below as well.

*Upstream Configuration* - The relationships between branches in each repo are key to what's going on here.  The fetch refspecs are going to govern that, and as long as they're set correctly no other "upstream" configuration should be required.

That said, the biggest change I make below is to move the cleaned-up branches in the bridge repository to their own `clean/*` namespace, so that fetching the right refs to the clean repository is *much* simpler.

*BFG removing original branches* - This is correct, but then after you configure the bridge repo's `origin` fetch refspec, the subsequent `fetch will recreate the original branches under the`prod/*` namespace.

*As to your last comment* - I think your previous attempts are just falling victim to errors that arise from the "rough draft" problems with the original answer.  Getting the right result is absolutely possible, and I guess as someone fully comfortable with the tools and techniques here I'm automatically looking past the "on-the-fly" corrections that would make it work.  But hopefully this rewrite will at least get you closer to what you're trying to do...

---

You mention that you may have to merge changes *from* the production repo *to* the cleaned-up repo.  That's not *too* bad a problem, but do beware that if you need to have changes flow in both directions - i.e. if you could want to update the production branch with changes form the cleaned-up repo - that complicates things and might favor a different approach.

Also, this is easiest if all changes flow from a *single branch* on the production repo into the clean repo.  (It doesn't matter if you use branches within the production repo, but you'd ideally want them all to be merged into a single branch, which becomes the source of changes for a single branch in the clean repo.)  If not, the same principles can apply, but the execution is harder.

Note that any approach is only as good as the ability to apply patches from production onto the cleaned code base.  To the extent that the cleaning only consists of removing certain files, that's no problem.  But if the repos diverge wildly, then conflicts when applying the changes will become an ever-increasing problem regardless of anything you might try.

---

For a one way flow (prod repo -> cleaned repo), you can keep one repo with both "original" and "cleaned" history.  This can be the production repo itself, or a dedicated "bridge repository".  (It cannot be the cleaned repository, as it would then contain the large history you're trying to remove from it.)

Exactly how to get to that state from where you are, depends on details of where you are.  For illustrative purposes, if you started with this approach in mind it might go like this:

You have your prod repo at `<prod-url>`.  You clone it, and this clone will be used to make a bridge repository.

```
$ git clone `<prod-url>` bridge
$ cd bridge
```

You run BFG in `bridge`, and then clone that to create the true "clean" repository.  Then (once again in `bridge`) you re-configure `origin` so that its branches can be mapped to a `prod` namespace in the `bridge` repo.

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/heads/prod/*
```

Now, when you fetch from origin to the bridge repo, instead of updating remote tracking refs, git will try to advance a set of branches in the `prod/` namespace.  But you *do not* want those `prod/*` branches fetched into your clean repo(s); the easiest way to fix that is to move the cleaned-up branches to a `clean/` namespace and reconfigure the clean repo to fetch only the `clean/*` branches.

In `bridge`, there are several ways to go about moving the branches.  If there aren't many, you could do it manually

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b clean/master
$ git branch -D master
```

For lots of branches, you could script this (perhaps using `git for-each-ref` to kick things off).  Or you could perhaps abuse the `filter-branch` backup ref mechanism in some way.

Anyway, once the branches are moved, go to the clean repo and

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/clean/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now taking a step back, unlike this last command, when I gave a fetch refspec for `origin` *in the bridge repo*, I omitted the leading `+` that is often used on fetch refspecs; that means that if a `prod` branch undergoes a history rewrite, the fetch will complain and you'll know you have a potential headache to resolve.  More on that later.

So next, in the bridge repo you can run

```
$ git fetch origin
```

which will re-load the original branches under the `prod/` namespace.

Now you have both the original branches (e.g. `refs/heads/prod/master`) and the clean branches (e.g. `refs/heads/clean/master`).  It could be drawn like this

```
A' -- B' -- C' -- D' <--(clean/master)

A -- B -- C -- D <--(prod/master)
```

The histories are unrelated, and you need to keep it that way.  But you also want to "know" that the `clean/master` branch is "up-to-date" through the `D` commit on `prod/master` in a way that makes merging future changes easy.  One way is to create two additional branches - let's call them `bridge-prod` and `bridge-clean`.

The `bridge-clean` branch will stay pointed at the last commit on which we brought changes in from `prod`.  New changes may go on in the `clean/` branches themselves, but `bridge-clean` will remember what a clean-up version of `prod` alone would look like.

```
$ git checkout clean/master
$ git branch bridge-clean
```

Then `bridge-prod`s job is to have the same content as `bridge-clean`, until it receives new changes from `prod/master` - after which it will be used as a reference for updating `bridge-clean` once again.

So to initialize that, we create a copy of `D'` whose parent is `D`.

```
git checkout prod/master
git checkout -b bridge-prod
git rm -r ':/'
git checkout bridge-clean -- ':/'
git commit
```

Now you have

```
A' -- B' -- C' -- D' <--(bridge-clean)(clean/master)

                  D" <--(bridge-prod)
                /
A -- B -- C -- D <--(prod/master)
```

where `D'` and `D"` have identical content (which is the "cleaned" version of `D`).  Because `D"` has `D` as its parent, you can merge future changes from `prod/master` into `bridge-prod` (`D` will be the merge base).  So after some time you have

```
                     ... x <--(clean/master)
                    /
A' -- B' -- C' -- D' <--(bridge-clean)

                  D" <--(bridge-prod)
                /
A -- B -- C -- D ... H <--(prod/master)
```

The two `...` could include many commits, branches, merges, whatever; it doesn't make a big difference.  The important thing is that `bridge-prod` and `bridge-clean` still represent the last integration between the repos.

So next you want to merge `prod/master` to `bridge-prod`.

```
                     ... x <--(clean/master)
                    /
A' -- B' -- C' -- D' <--(bridge-clean)

                 D" -- H"<--(bridge-prod)
                /     /
A -- B -- C -- D ... H <--(prod/master)
```

You want `H"` to represent the cleaned-up state of `H`.  For that, there are two conditions to worry about:

If the `prod/master` branch updates a file that was removed by the clean-up, then the merge will conflict.  Luckily these removals are the only changes on "our" side of the merge, and we know we want to keep them over whatever `prod/master` might have done to those files.  So when we merge we could say

```
git checkout bridge-prod
git merge -X ours prod/master
```

The `-X ours` option should not be confused with `-s ours`.  While `-s ours` would use the "ours merge strategy", ignoring the `prod/master` changes entirely, `-X ours` uses the default merge strategy with the "ours strategy option" (thanks, git, for the clear-as-mud naming).

What this means is, this command will try to merge as normal, but every time there's a conflict the `bridge-prod` version of that hunk of code will prevail.  Since the only changes on `bridge-prod` are removal of files we don't want, this is good.

The other problem would be if `prod/master` might have added a new file that should be excluded from the clean-up.  If you know that can't happen, no problem.  If it *could* happen, then you need to check for it.  For example before merging you could say

```
git diff prod/master prod/master^
```

and see if there are any new files that you wouldn't want in the clean repo.  If so, then for your merge do

```
git checkout bridge-prod
git merge -X ours --no-commit prod/master
# remove the unwanted files
git add ':/'
git commit
```

Now, because `D"` is the same content as `D'`, that means that `H"` has the `TREE` you want in the next `bridge-clean` commit.

```
git checkout bridge-clean
git rm -r ':/'
git checkout bridge-prod -- ':/'
git commit
```

This gives you

```
                     ... x <--(clean/master)
                    /
A' -- B' -- C' -- D' -- H' <--(bridge-clean)

                 D" -- H"<--(bridge-prod)
                /     /
A -- B -- C -- D ... H <--(prod/master)
```

`H'` has the same content as `H"` - which is the sanitized content, updated through `H`.  Also, `H'` has sanitized history (it's parent is `D'`, which we cleaned up at the outset), so it can safely be included in the clean repo.  You can merge `bridge-clean` to `master` and the change transfer is complete.

This is conceptually a bit involved, and takes some up-front setup (and maybe writing a few scripts to use with each integration of changes).  But once that's all set up, it minimizes the manual fiddling and lets you make the best applicable use of the merge machinery git provides.

However, it's a one way bridge.  If you were to merge `bridge-prod` back into `prod/master`, you would almost certainly delete files that you want kept in `prod/master`.

If you do have to take changes from the clean repo and apply them to the prod repo, you could generate a patch on the clean repo.  Tot he extent that the clean repo content is a subset of the prod repo content, the patch should apply without too much hassle.  It might cause some spurious conflicts the next time you merge changes from prod down to clean.

One last additional point (mentioned above but then forgotten) - This all assumes that you won't be doing history rewrites in the `prod` repo going forward (or at least not often).  If you were to do such a rewrite, then just as another user's clone couldn't cleanly pull changes, the bridge wouldn't work normally for integrating the change into the clean repo.  You'd have to work out a procedure based on the specifics of the situation.

Comment: thank you for such comprehensive and detailed guide!  _"Flow in both directions"_ - this is not a problem, it's only one-way, from _production_ (and only from one branch) to _cleaned-up_ branch. So I guess this part is "WIN".:)

I need to read and try thoroughly what you wrote, but I think I get your suggested approach with `bridge` repo - it totally makes sense (it's like many-to-many relation - with something in between).;)

Comment: It would be more perfect to have it without _bridge_ repo and have only _production_. We could modify it a bit, but I'm not sure how to prepare a _clean_ branch inside _production, leaving other parts untouched for production builds.
Anyway,  approach with _bridge_ repo is also good enough. The thing that eventually we will ditch _production_ branch for all, but it already had to happen half a year ago. So I'm already tired waiting and want more reliable approach.

Comment: I think I started to mention, you could do this without a *dedicated* bridge repo, in that the prod repo could contain the bridge branches and the clean history as well.  Then your clean repo would reference prod as a remote, but you'd set its refspec so that it only ever fetches the clean history.  Then as long as the server-side git implementation doesn't get clever and send more than was requested, it would still work fine.  The setup is similar to above, but you'd set things up to map the bridge branches (and possibly the clean branches) back into the prod repo.

Comment: I was busy with some other urgent stuff, therefore hadn't chance to play with it (and that's why still didn't mark it as accepted answer). Now I'm trying it and there some gaps for me... Maybe you can clarify it, maybe it was too obvious for you.;)
You mentioned upstream branch, but I didn't get where exactly you configured it.Is it where you set `remote.origin.fetch`?
Another most important finalization point is not clear for me: how to merge clean branch from `bridge` repository to `clean` repository? Actually for me it was the main question, not how to update with changes from production.

Comment: I keep reading it again and again, and still struggling to get the part between:
`You run BFG in bridge, and then clone that to create the true "clean" repository. Then (once again in bridge) you re-configure origin so that its branches can be mapped to ...`

and 

`Now you have both the original branches (e.g. refs/heads/prod/master) and the clean branches (e.g. refs/heads/master). It could be drawn like this ...`

After I run BFG there is no longer "original" branches.. How come there are "both" without configuring upstream branch to real "original" one?

Comment: I somehow managed to merge something following your suggestions.. I mean I have same changes in my `clean` repository as in `prod` repository, BUT - it still ends with messed up history. Repository became twice times larger after this merge (clean history + old history).
So either I do something wrong, or it's just how it is... And thinking more deeply - it makes sense. Probably you can cherry-pick last merge commit from bridge-repo to clean-repo, but doing fullway merge - not fully possible without messing histories I guess...

Comment: @Aleksanderis - Sorry, been offline for a bit.  I'm reviewing your questions and will see if I can provide any useful clarification

Comment: ... I just got 90% through a rewrite and accidentally deleted it because on-page editing interfaces are the worst.  This could take a bit of time.

Comment: Duh, really sorry for your rewrite.. ;)
All what I can suggest is something what I'm usually doing - write everything in some thing, which automatically saves what you write, and won't be lost in case of accidental browser refresh or something (e.g. Google Keep).
By the way if you are editing your suggested solution - you might drop the part about harder two-way merge (to support merges from `clean` to `prod`). Because it adds some additional confusion, and I already clarified in original post, that it's not really needed.:)

Comment: I reviewed your updates and still confused about your mentioned `Upstream Configuration` and refspecs. So, should I configure upstream branches at all or not??
Otherwise I don't get this part:
`you re-configure origin so that its branches can be mapped to a prod namespace in the bridge repo. $git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/heads/prod/*`
How you can reference origin fetch like this if it sits in a different remote repository? Or if it's same repository - how it can be true `fetch will recreate the original branches under the prod/*` after BFG cleanup?

Comment: @Aleksanderis - Your questions are not clear to me at this point.  "...should I configure upstream branches at all or not??"  If such a configuration step should be required, I would have listed it.  "How can you reference origin fetch like this if it sits in a different remote repository?"  That's what refspecs do.  The source for a fetch is always a ref in the other repo.

Comment: You already mentioned previously that you had missed some steps in your "draft" version. That's why I wanted to double-check regarding upstream branches configurations, but now at least this part is clear.;)
`The source for a fetch is always a ref in the other repo.` - but how?.. If there is no upstream configured, how it may know about other repo at all? Maybe I'm missing something in this regard, or some initial configuration differs.. Maybe when you do initial steps - something should be left in local Git repo? (Git always stores something, until "git gc" or smth..)

Comment: What I mean about "git gc", is that as final step with BFG cleanup you need to execute: `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`.

So maybe it shouldn't be done in your suggested solution?

Comment: @Aleksanderis - Look at your config after cloning a repo. It keeps reference to the remote. You are confusing remote configuration with upstream configuration. I would read up on the docs (clone, fetch, and config pages would be good starting points). If you try this procedure and it doesn't work, and you can show the specific commands and output showing the problem, then I'll be happy to discuss further corrections. However, my willingness to spend time repeating documented git fundamentals evaporated when you referenced 1st-draft errors as an excuse to insinuate problems with the revision.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your effort - really appreciated! Sorry for some obvious/stupid questions.:)
Actually regarding all this clone/fetch order - maybe I missed saying it specifically, that I already had BFG'ed repository, which might be the reason it didn't fully fit your solution. In order to go your solution step by step - I would need to BFG it again, which is complicated for 10-years old repository.
At this moment I also a bit jaded with it - it needed more effort than benefit it would give. However I think I will get back to it at some point, but with more fresh head.