# Git: multiple remotes + sparseCheckout + shallow clone

Tags: git

I want to clone a part of a repository. To be more specific repository is https://github.com/helm/charts, part I'm only interested in - `stable/airflow`. After that, I'm planning to make some changes and commit them in my private repo. Periodically I want to rebase with `helm/charts` repo. There are some additional criteria:
- Keep in my private repo only `stable/airflow` directory
- Fetch as minimum metadata as possible from `helm/charts` repo

My first approach was adding two remotes, using sparseCheckout setting and fetch with `depth=1`. This brought me some difficulties: I couldn't keep my repo clean from waste folders (sparseCheckout ~= sparsePush), pushing to my origin doesn't work with shallow clone.

Currently, I ended with making two "git" folders: `.git` (my repo) and `.helm_git` (helm repo). The last one still uses sparseCheckout and shallow clone. These repo-s don't know anything about each other and can track only changed files. (so no mixed commit history). But this is not satisfied me too. I have to put both folders in `.gitignore` file. And therefore every developer should set them on his own.

Do you see any other possibilities to solve initial problem?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an easy way, nor a way I would recommend, to do exactly what you're asking.

In git, storage is organized around `COMMIT`s - snapshots of *the entire project content* - rather than around files.  A subset of the files is a different content, so requires a different `COMMIT`.  (This relates to your comment about "sparse push"; there cannot be such a thing in git.)

So you can limit the commits you store - by only cloning specific refs and/or by using the `--depth` argument to create a shallow clone.  But particularly if you want to be able to integrate upstream changes going forward, it is not at all easy to limit the set of files in the commits you keep.

Before getting into how, I strongly suggest you take another look at *why* you would go to the effort of doing that.  It's not going to save that much space.  (The total repo history is about 17MB, with an 11MB working tree on the tip of the default branch.  The project might benefit from using `git lfs` for some large assets, but even the full size of the repo as-is just isn't that much to worry about in most modern environments.)  If you just want to have a less clutter-y worktree, then as you've noted sparse checkouts work for that even if the repo itself stores everything.

If you still want to try to do it, then you'll need to create a "bridge repostiory" that will store both their history (or a part of it), and yours.  This will involve at least one extra branch, non-standard merging procedures, and overall just a brittle change integration process.  In other words, it will be neither smaller nor simpler than just working with the full commits.

You can find the patterns you would need to follow to create such a procedure in a previous answer here: [Merge upstream branch into fork with rewritten history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117443/merge-upstream-branch-into-fork-with-rewritten-history/52119399#52119399)